# How would I mimic this conditional inclusion of resources in JSF 2?

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, conditional-comments

In short, I'd like to do this (the conditional part, i know how to include with `<h:outputStyleSheet>`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[path-to-dist]/leaflet.css" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="[path-to-dist]/leaflet.ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

In JSF 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<h:outputText escape="false">`

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if lte IE 8]&gt;&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;[path-to-dist]/leaflet.ie.css&quot;/&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />
```

Yes, it's a line of ugliness, but there's really no other way as Facelets is inherently a XML based view technology.

---

**Update**: if you happen to use the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), you can just use [its `<o:conditionalComment>` component](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/conditionalComment).

```
<o:conditionalComment if="lte IE 8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="[path-to-dist]/leaflet.ie.css" />
</o:conditionalComment>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to wrap `<h:outputText value="#{bean.pathToDist}" />` to your link. Like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<h:outputText value="#{bean.pathToDist}" />/leaflet.css" />`.

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
<f:verbatim>
&lt;!--[if IE]&gt;
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file.css" />
&lt;![endif]--&gt;
</f:verbatim>
```

Comment: OP is using Facelets, not JSP.

Answer (score -1):

I tryed this:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="blueprint/screen.css" />
<f:verbatim>&lt;!--[if lt IE 8]&gt;</f:verbatim>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="blueprint/ie.css" />
<f:verbatim>&lt;![endif]--&gt;</f:verbatim>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="esap.css" />
```

the html output was:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/esap/javax.faces.resource/blueprint/screen.css.xhtml?ln=css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/esap/javax.faces.resource/blueprint/ie.css.xhtml?ln=css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/esap/javax.faces.resource/esap.css.xhtml?ln=css" />
```

the conditional html was put before the stylesheet links.

Comment: Hi, this section is for answers, not for questions. If you have a question, press "Ask Question" button on right top.